# c# forward Email from Outlook inbox

Tags: c#, email, outlook, forwarding

I want to forward an existing Email from my Outlook inbox folder. On recent research I found some different solutions:

- get the current mail item and copy it to a new message
- move method to move in a different folder
- forward method...

My goal is to find a simple way to forward an existing Email to another **E-Mail adress**.

My code enclosed does **not** have access to send!

```
private void buttonExplorer_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Selection mySelection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = null;
    foreach (Object obj in mySelection)
    {
        if (obj is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            mailItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)obj;
            mailItem.Forward();
            mailItem.Recipients.Add("test@web.com");
            mailItem.Send();
        }
    }
}
```

Would be nice if there is a simple way to solve the forwarding event issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Forward()` creates a new item, as stated **[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_methods.aspx)**.

So you'll need to use that new item from then on:

```
var newItem = mailItem.Forward();
newItem.Recipients.Add("to.alt@web.de");
newItem.Send();
```

Comment: Perfect! Thx. Do you know if attachements would be sent with?

Comment: Just tested - attachements are copied with and sent succusfully

Answer (score -1):

Try using Microsoft Exchange Web Service (EWS) to forward the email messages. EWS provides api for the commonly used events.

A sample code would like this,

```
// Connect to Exchange Web Services as user1 at contoso.com.
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user1@contoso.com", "password ");
service.AutodiscoverUrl("user1@contoso.com");

// Create the e-mail message, set its properties, and send it to user2@contoso.com, saving a copy to the Sent Items folder. 
EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
message.Subject = "Interesting";
message.Body = "The proposition has been considered."; 
message.ToRecipients.Add("user2@contoso.com");
message.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

For more info, refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633681(v=exchg.80).aspx